# How would I be able to populate all empty href attributes using php based on a condition?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to replace all empty `href` attributes in my php file based on a condition.  I've tried using `str_repalce()` but that doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to use `DOMDocument` as I think it wouldn't be necessary because what I'm trying to do's look for all `href` attributes in my php file, which are currently empty, and replacing them with a link.

I've seen this question asked before but it didn't seem to work for me.

Side note: I currently have an `<img>` inside all of my `<a href="">`s (`<a href=""><img/></a>`). I only want to populate the empty `href` attributes.

How can I achieve this?

```
$getQueryParam = $_GET['type'];

switch ($getQueryParam) {
    case 'blue':
        preg_replace('/^<a href="#(.*?)"[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>/', '', 'mylink.com');
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, obligatory "[do not parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/231316)" followed by "[if you control the HTML it *might* be safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/231316)".

You're definition of "empty" is a little vague. Your sample is using literally empty but the RegEx you are showing has a `#` in it. Regardless, I came up with two ways.

I personally don't like `preg_replace` too much unless I'm using it to remove something, but that's just me, and it isn't wrong to use. This first example just looks for an opening `<a` tag, followed by non-greedy match for non-closing tag `>`, followed by an `href="`, a hash or space, a closing `"` and anything else until `>`. This can very easily break, for instance if you have spaces around the `href =`  or if you use different quotes, but that's a bridge to cross later possibly.

```php
$testData = [
    '<a href=""><img/></a>',
    '<a href="#"><img/></a>',
    '<a class="button" href="#" rel="nofollow"><img/></a>',
    '<a href=""><img/></a>',
];

foreach ($testData as $test) {
    echo preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*?href=")(?:#|\s+)?("[^>]*>)/', '$1https://example.com$2', $test), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The second version uses `DOMDocument` which I know you said you didn't want to use, but honestly it allows you to reason about things such better, to the point that I don't think it needs any more comment.

```php
$testData = [
    '<a href=""><img/></a>',
    '<a href="#"><img/></a>',
    '<a class="button" href="#" rel="nofollow"><img/></a>',
    '<a href=""><img/></a>',
];

foreach ($testData as $test) {
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($test, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
        if (in_array(trim($tag->getAttribute('href')), ['#', ''], true)) {
            $tag->setAttribute('href', 'https://example.com');
        }
    }
    echo $d->saveHTML(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

I will note, the DOMDocument might change your HTML just slightly, however for most people these days, HTML vs XHTML doesn't really matter much anymore.